# Finding the magnitude of a vector product between two vectors?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, vector-analysis

Vector $\overrightarrow{A}$ has magnitude $11.0m$ and vector $\overrightarrow{B}$ has magnitude $16.0m$ . The scalar product $\overrightarrow{A}\bullet \overrightarrow{B}$ is $79.0m^2$.

What is the magnitude of the vector product between these two vectors?

I'm not exactly sure how to get started with this problem and would appreciate tips just to get me going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way to get it:

You know the lengths of the two vectors and that $ \ \vec{A} \bullet \vec{B} \ $ is given by $ || \vec{A} ||  \cdot  || \vec{B} || \ \cos \theta \ $ . The magnitude of $ \ \vec{A} \ \times \ \vec{B}  \ $ is $ || \vec{A} ||  \cdot  || \vec{B} || \ \sin \theta \ , $ so find $ \ \cos \theta \ $ and use $ \ \sin \theta \ = \ \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 \theta} \ $ .

Comment: Awesome!  I almost got it then!

Comment: I must be calculating the $cos(\theta)$ incorrectly.  I get $\theta=cos\frac{16}{11}$

Comment: It should be $ \ \cos \theta  =  \frac{79}{11 \cdot 16} \ , $ no?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Thank you

Comment: Using your assistance above I get $11.0(16.0)sin(.8936)$ which is not the correct answer.  The $.8936$ came from $sin(\theta)=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{79}{11(16)}\right)^2}$

Comment: Did you take the sine _of_ 0.8936?  That already _is_ the sine of the angle, so you should just use $ \ 11 \cdot 16 \cdot 0.8936 \ . $

Comment: Then that's what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\sin^{2}\theta=1-\cos^{2}\theta$
**Further Hint:** $|\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B}|=|\vec{A}| |\vec{B}|\cos\theta$ and $|\vec{A} \times \vec{B}|=|\vec{A}||\vec{B}|\sin\theta$

Comment: A little more haha :)

Comment: I wasn't sure how much you knew, so I was trying to give away as little as possible, hah!

Comment: No worries!  thx